# how to add background in j2me

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

Now I am developing a mobile application, I have developed menu by Canvas and I get stuck when I try to add background into application.

It means that I need to add background into my application and menu can visible on this background.

I am trying to find the way to add background into j2me, and I use array for menu and I found an example about adding background in J2me using `TiledLayer` and `Layermanager`, therefore that I just add these objects into my code for test.

Can it become a background in my code? I can not make it work that way

Comment: I do not understand the use of the LayerManager object ! You do not use it in your code !

Comment: first of all thank you comment, because im newbie in J2ME and i try to find the way to add background into j2me, and i use array for menu and i find a example about add background in J2me used TiledLayer and Layermanager, there for that i just add them into my code for test Can it become a background in my code? but it cant

Answer (score 2):

> add background in J2me used TiledLayer and Layermanager

given above, first of all consider using [GameCanvas](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/game/GameCanvas.html) instead of Canvas

```
    public class MainMenu extends GameCanvas //...
```

Studying some introductory tutorials wouldn't hurt either:

- [Exploring the Game API of MIDP 2.0](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/07/07/j2me3.html)
- [Getting Started With the MIDP 2.0 Game API](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/gameapi/)

By the way both above tutorials provide detailed explanations how to use `TiledLayer` and `LayerManager` for adding background